# Dell XPS 15 9575 Laptop not connecting to WIFI and disrupting current WIFI connections

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wireless-router

My Dell XPS 15 9575 will not stay connected to my Netgear N750 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit router. It will find it and connect for two minutes then drop the connection between router and laptop but also drop other connections in the house (phone, smart tv, etc). Then when I open the available networks, my network no longer shows.

I am able to connect to my phone hotspot and it stays connected.

I tried reinstalling my wireless network adapter but after I reinstalled, the same issue occurred.

Have you ever had a laptop disable all current wireless connections? Is it because of the router? This hasn't been an issue with any other laptop I've used ay home.

Comment: Try updating the firmware in your router to the newest version.

Comment: John - I was finally able to update my firmware and I believe that has resolved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I will post my comment as an answer and I hope you will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> Have you ever had a laptop disable all current wireless connections?
> Is it because of the router? This hasn't been an issue with any other
> laptop I've used at home.

A good solution here would be to update the firmware in the router.  Try that.

Comment by OP is that firmware update did work